# how to display elements of array one by one on clicking next button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried many solutions but they are not working for my purpose.
Here is my complete PHP working code for generating a random expression only for single digit numbers.

```
      <?php
      error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
           if(isset($_POST['play']))
        {
       //validation for no of operation selected
       $operation = $_POST['operation'];
       if(empty($operation)) 
             {
               echo "Please Select at least one operation <br/>";
             }
              else
              {  
                 $N = count($operation); //count selected operation
              ?>
              <div class="slideshow-container" id="slide">
                 <center>
                  <?php 
                    echo  "<br />";
                    echo "<span style= 'font-size: 20px;'><i>This is your generated sequence !<br><br></span>";
                    echo "<span style= 'font-size: 18px;'><i>You have selected $N operation(s):"; 

                     for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  //for loop for for operator array.
                        {
                          echo($operation[$i] . ", "); //display selected operation
                        }
                        echo "<br />";
                   ?>                              
                </center>
              </div>
                  <?php
                     //checkbox operations
                    if($N==1)   //if only one operation is selected
                        {
                             if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                                 {
                                      $rOperators = array('+');                           
                                 }
                                else if($operation[0]=='Subtraction')
                                   {
                                      $rOperators = array('-');
                                    }
                                    else if($operation[0]=='Multiplication')
                                      {
                                      $rOperators = array('*');
                                       }
                                        else
                                          {
                                            $rOperators = array('/');
                                          }
                        }
                    else if ($N==2) //if only two operations are selected by the user
                     {
                        if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                            {
                                if($operation[1]=='Subtraction')
                                    {
                                        $rOperators = array('+','-');
                                    }
                                     else if($operation[1]=='Multiplication')
                                         {
                                           $rOperators = array('+','*');
                                         }
                                          else
                                             {
                                               $rOperators = array('+','/');
                                             }                           
                            }
                            else if($operation[0]=='Subtraction')
                            {
                                if($operation[1]=='Multiplication')
                                     {
                                        $rOperators = array('-','*');
                                     }
                                    else
                                      {
                                        $rOperators = array('-','/');
                                      }
                            }
                              else
                                {
                                  $rOperators = array('*','/');
                                }
                      }
                        else if ($N==3) //if 3 o
                            {
                                if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                                 {
                                     if($operation[1]=='Subtraction')
                                         {
                                             if($operation[2]=='Multiplication')
                                             {
                                                 $rOperators = array('+','-','*');    
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 $rOperators = array('+','-','/');
                                             }

                                         }
                                      else
                                         {
                                              $rOperators = array('+','*','/');
                                         }                         
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     $rOperators = array('-','*','/');
                                 }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $rOperators = array('+','-','*','/');
                            }                            
             }
       //display sequence having only single digit numbers
         if($_POST['digits'] == 1)
        {
        $q = $_POST['que'];
             $previousInt = null;        //Track the previous operand
             $s = $_POST['select'];

              //display inputs given by user through form
             ?>
             <div class="slideshow-container" id="slide">
             <center>
              <?php 
              echo "<span style= 'font-size: 18px;'><i>No.of questions:".$q. "<br />";
              echo "<span style= 'font-size: 18px;'><i>No. of integers:" .$s. "<br />";
              echo  "<span style= 'font-size: 18px;'><i>No of digits: 1 <br />";
              ?>                    
              </center>
              <?php
                     for ($x = 1; $x<=$q; $x++) //for loop for no. of questions
                        {
                           $randomOperands = array();
                            $randomOperators = array();

                                    // loop over $i n times
                                   for ($i = 1; $i <=$s; $i++) //for loop for no. of integers user entered
                                     {
                                        $nextInt = rand(1, 9); // assign random operand to array slot
                                         $randomOperands[] = $nextInt;
                                            if($i < $s)
                                             {   
                                               if($previousInt === 0) //No operator after last opearnd
                                                  {
                                                 //avoid division-by-zero
                                                   $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, 2)];
                                                  }
                                                else
                                                  {
                                                   $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, $N-1)];
                                                  } 
                                              }  
                                        $previousInt = $nextInt;
                                      }

                                    // print array values:
                                   $exp = '';  
                                      $output_string = " ";
                                          //Generating the expression
                                           foreach($randomOperands as $key=>$value1)
                                         {
                                          $exp .=  $value1 . "" ;
                                             $output_string .= $value1."<br>";
                                             if(isset($randomOperators[$key]))
                                                {
                                                 $exp .=  $randomOperators[$key]  ."";
                                                  $output_string .= $randomOperators[$key]."<br>";
                                                }

                                         }
                                          //print expression

                                          $res = eval("return ($exp);");//evaluate the expression
                                           $generate = array($output_string, $res);
                    ?> 
                         <div class="mySlider">

                         <!--  go back to previous element of expression , for inner slider-->
                                          <a class="back" id= "pre" onclick="addSlides(-1)" style="float: left; top: 46%; position: absolute; right: 800px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 27px;">❮</a>

                                 <!--display of the expression-->
                                           <cemter>  <?php
                                              echo '<span style= "font-size: 27px;"<br>Q('.$x.')<br><br>'.$output_string.'</span><br>';             
                                             ?>

                                   <!-- generate result with show button-->  
                                         <div class="ansdiv"><?php echo '<span style= "font-size: 27px;"<br>____<br>'.$res."<br>"; ?></div><br></cemter>

                                      <!--  go to next element of expression , for inner slider-->
                                    <a class="front" id = "fro" onclick="addSlides(1)" style="float: right; top: 46%; position: absolute; left: 800px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 27px;">❯</a>    
                             </div>
            <?php   } ?>
                             <center><input type="button" name="show" value="*****" id="show">
                                      <!-- eye icon for show answer-->
                                      <img src="Images/Eye.png" id = "open"></center>
        <?php   } 
         ?>                      </div>
                           <a class="prev" id= "prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">Previous</a>
                           <a class="next" id = "next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">Next</a>
                   <div class="dot-container">
                         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                     </div>
       <?php
        }
       ?> 
                               <script>
                //script for generate one by one questions
              var slideIndex = 1;
              showSlides(slideIndex);
                function plusSlides(n) 
                  {
                    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                  }

                function currentSlide(n) 
                    {
                      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                    }

               function showSlides(n) {
                   var i;
                   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlider");
                   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
                     for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
                         {
                          slides[i].style.display = "none";  
                         }
                     for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) 
                     {
                       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                     }
                       slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                     }
               </script>

               <script>
                                        //shw answer on clicking show button 
                                         $(document).ready(function(){
                                           //show when eye icon clicked
                                          $("#open").click(function(){  
                                             $(".ansdiv").toggle();
                                           }); 
                                          //show when show button clicked
                                          $("#show").click(function(){  
                                             $(".ansdiv").toggle();
                                           });
                                          $("#next").click(function(){  
                                             $(".ansdiv").hide();
                                           });
                                          });
                            </script>
```

Here is my form

```
        <body>
    <?php if(!isset($_POST['play'])) 
      {
       ?>
<div class="main-container">


        <h3><I>GENERATE HERE !</I></h3>
          <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-25">
                   <label for="qnum">Select no.of questions:</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class = "col-75"><input type="number" id="qnum" name="que" value="1"  min="1" max="100"></div>
                     <br /><br />
               </div>
             <br />

        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="int">How many numbers you want in a sequence? :</label></div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                       <select name="select" id="int">
                        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                        <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
      </div>
      <br /> 

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25">
             <label for="dig">Select no. of digits:</label></div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <select name="digits" id="dig">
                   <option value="1"> 1 Digit </option>

                   </select>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br />
        </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25"><label>Select operations:</label><br /></div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="checkbox" id="mix" value="all" class="toggle-button"><label>All</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation[]" value="Addition" checked><label>Addition</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation[]" value="Subtraction"><label>Subtraction</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation[]" value="Multiplication"><label>Multiplication</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation[]" value="Division"><label>Division</label>
               </div>
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
            </div><br />


        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Generate" id="gen"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="play" value="Play" id="play">
        <br><br>
         <br />
 </form>
  </div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      $( '.col-75 .toggle-button' ).click( function () {
          $( '.col-75 input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
      })
    </script>

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#show").click(function(){  
                         $(".ansdiv").show();
                             });
                          });
                </script> 
      </center>

      <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#gen").click(function(){  
                         $("#play").show();
                           $("#gen").hide();
                             });
                          });
                </script> 



  <?php } 
    include 'operate.php'; 
    ?>
  </body>
```

Here is screenshot of output I am getting:

[image]

As you can see in screenshot, the expression is generating with its result. The `$output_string` is the expression and `$res` is result of expression. They both are stored in array named `$generate`.

Now I want to show the all the elements of array one by one on clicking next button i.e the first element should be 4 according to screenshot and after clicking next button, there should be - operator and so on until the result displayed at last.

NOTE - Here everytime the value of `$output_string` variable  will be different because the expressions are generating randomly and accordingly the result will also changed. This is working fine for my purpose but I tried many solution and  I am unable somehow to display the elements one by one.

How can I fix it? Please help me.

Comment: Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a seeded random generator for generating random numbers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php
With seeded random generator, you can generate a sequence of random numbers that is always the same for that particular seed value.

You can have a hidden field in the form that will tell you what is the seed value, which will ensure that you will be able to create the same random sequence for that seed.

```php
// Picks a random element from $array
function get_random_item($array) {
    $array_length = count($array);
    if ($array_length) {
        return $array[rand(0, $array_length - 1)];
    }
    return null;
}

// Generates a random digit
function generate_random_digit() {
    return rand(0, 9);
}

// Generates a random number that has $num_digits
function generate_random_operand($num_digits) {
    $operand = "";
    while ($num_digits--) {
        $operand += generate_random_digit();
    }
    return $operand;
}

// Generates a simple algebraic expression in form of an array
function generate_expression($num_operands, $operators, $max_digits = 1) {
    $expression = array();
    while ($num_operands--) {
        $expression[] = generate_random_operand($max_digits);
        if ($num_operands) {
            $expression[] = get_random_item($operators);
        }
    }
    return $expression;
}
// On server request, you would then:
// 1. read the values from the $_POST array
// 2. set the random seed using the seed variable sent via POST params
// 3. generate the expression
// 4. render your view
function render_expression() {
    $seed = $_POST['seed'] ?? rand();
    $num_operands = $_POST['s'] ?? 2;
    $operators = array_map(function($operation_name) {
        // this map function converts array that looks like:
        //    ['Addition', 'Multiplication']
        // into an array that looks like
        //    ['+', '*']
        switch($operation_name) {
            case 'Subtraction': 
                return '-';
            case 'Multiplication':
                return '*';
            case 'Division':
                return '/';
            case 'Addition': 
                // fall through to default
            default: 
                return '+';
        }
    }, $_POST['operation'] ?? []);
    $expression = generate_expression($num_operands, $operators);
    echo implode(" ", $expression);
}
```

For showing the operands one by one, after button click, you could have another hidden form field that would keep a value of the operand counter, and then render that many expression operands as indicated by that variable.

I would suggest to do it on the client-side though. Something like this:

```js
function showNextHiddenItem(btn) {
  var nextHiddenSpan = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('span.hidden');
  if (nextHiddenSpan) {
    nextHiddenSpan.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('button.next')].forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', showNextHiddenItem));
```

```css
.expression span.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="expression">
  <span class="hidden">4</span>
  <span class="hidden">-</span>
  <span class="hidden">2</span>
  <span class="hidden">+</span>
  <span class="hidden">5</span>
  <span class="hidden">*</span>
  <span class="hidden">8</span>
  <span class="hidden">=</span>
  <span class="hidden">42</span>
  <div><button class="next">Next</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply its very useful to me I tried it. but I am confused in functions thaat how they can be used for my code , can you help me in that?

Comment: @user10625430 I started working on your source code, but it is not complete, it's cut off

Comment: hey thanks for the help , and How can I provide you the source code ? becaus the problem is not yet solved , I am unable to fix it .

Comment: hey , ArtBIT  , now I have updated my full source code in my above post. Can you please take a look at it and suggest me how can I do it properly because I am trying hard to fix it but not working somehow? Thank you.

Comment: @ ArtBIT , Please help me I have uploaded full code in my above post, the problem is still not fixed even after so many tries.

Comment: @user10625430 https://gist.github.com/ArtBIT/206d0bf923e0988f307f1040f6e35ed0 but promise me that next time you are going to do your homework by yourself ;)

Comment: Thank you so much ,, I will  take your code as reference and use it accordingly in my existing code so that I can get more clear idea about logic.

Comment: but your code is not generating output  after form submit it is showing numeric error and thats why the expression is not displaying

Comment: I will fix it .

Comment: @ ArtBIT I fixed that errorbut  still not displaying the expression

Comment: @user10625430 I don't get any errors. I just downloaded and extracted the zip file from the gist, started the php server in that directory `php -S localhost:8080 -t .` and opened http://localhost:8080/slideshow.php in the browser. I use PHP 7.2

Comment: hey its woring now thanks. and also got the clear idea about  how to use proper logic.

Comment: @ ArtBIT   where should I include that hidden class functionality to show the elements in expressions one by one ? In earlier post you have given these functionality for already specified numbers and operands and in my case where shoulld I put that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184403/discussion-between-artbit-and-user10625430).

Comment: @ ArtBIT please guide me throug this

Comment: can you pleach check out the chat discussion forum  where I have posted my issue and guide me

Comment: Its a very small issue but somewhere I am going wrong , It would be great if you check that out .

Comment: @ ArtBIT   hey  can you please check out the chat discussion for once , its really important to me , please